# Why is array giving a wrong value when using two classes?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have this code here.

```
public class ArrayChallenge {

private static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Number of integers: ");
    int num = kb.nextInt();

    int [] returnedArray = readIntegers(num);
    System.out.println("Ascending Order: " + printAsc(returnedArray));
}

public static int [] readIntegers(int count){
    int [] values = new int[count];
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        values[i] = kb.nextInt();
    }
    return values;
}

public static int [] printAsc(int [] theArray){
    Arrays.sort(theArray);
    return  theArray;
}
```

The code above works perfectly fine. I have only one class but several static methods and during calling the method *printAsc(returnedArray)*, the program will return a set of arrays in a format just like using *.toString*

I took this code to a next level using two classes and making the static methods to instance methods. However when i print the arrays. It prints these values *[I@643b1d11*

Here is my code below:

Main Class

```
public class Main {

public static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of elements: ");
    int num = kb.nextInt();

    int numArrays []  = new int[num];

    Minimum minimum = new Minimum();
    int [] returnedArrays = minimum.readIntegers(numArrays);
    int returnedMin = minimum.findMin(returnedArrays);

    System.out.println("Minimum Value: " + returnedMin);
    System.out.println("Ascending Arrays: " + minimum.arrayAsc(returnedArrays));
}
```

}

Minimum Class

```
public class Minimum {

public int [] readIntegers(int [] numArrays){
    System.out.println("Enter " + numArrays.length + " integers:");
    for(int i=0; i< numArrays.length; i++){
        numArrays[i]=Main.kb.nextInt();
    }
    return numArrays;
}

public int findMin(int [] numArrays){
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=0;i<numArrays.length;i++){
        if(max>numArrays[i]){
            max = numArrays[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public int [] arrayAsc(int [] numArrays){
    Arrays.sort(numArrays);
    return numArrays;
}
```

}

How did the result of my arrays became like that? Can someone explain the process to me? Much appreciate.
Also, i used the debug method because im using Intellij, It didnt really show anything.

Comment: The code you wrote that "works perfectly fine" can't possibly work fine. `printAsc` returns an array. An array cannot be printed directly - you have to use `Arrays.toString` or a loop. Perhaps you were running an old version of it where `printAsc` did something else.

Comment: @RealSkeptic thank you for pointing that out. It was indeed because of the old version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are using `printAsc`, you need to change its definition to return a String.

```
public static String printAsc(int [] theArray){
    Arrays.sort(theArray);
    return  Arrays.toString(theArray);
}
```

If you do not want to change the definition of `printAsc`, you need to call it as follows:

```
System.out.println("Ascending Order: " + Arrays.toString(printAsc(returnedArray)));
```

Comment: yeah i did that  however i want to use an array int as the return type and i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: i see you've edited it. Thank you for that answer. I didn't know its capable of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just print an Array and expect it to read out all the values. When printing, Java casts the value into a `String`. By default, when dealing with `Objects`, Java will simply print the name of the `Object`'s class and its Hash value. This is what you see. You can read more about it [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method).

If you want to parse the Array into a `String` that hold all the members of the Array, you might want to take a look at the [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) method (and [how to use it](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_tostring_int.htm)).

Comment: yes I can convert it from Arrays.toString. However I want to return a int array in the instance method.